# Python 2.7 disregarding else and combined "if not" statements

Tags: python, if-statement

I'm not *too* new to Python, but have only just now started messing with it more as of recent. Ambiguous issues aside, I need help in regards to figuring out why my code isn't listening to the provided `else` or `if not` statements.

[My code is way too big to place into a code block, but necessary for context. Here's the link to a Google Docs document, with the problematic piece highlighted.](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1I9-ruoRm0IFvgLijdhfKWgRsdTBzL7ZFaSObXHErquY/edit?usp=sharing)

What *should* happen is that, when prompted for your gender, placing anything other than "m", "f", or "o" (or the same capitalized) will throw the `else` statement. This does not happen, however, and defaults to if your input was "m".

Comment: Don't link to code; include it in the question itself. If it's "way too big", then you need to distill it down to a minimal example that demonstrates the problem. This is a [mcve].

Comment: Okay, thanks! I'll keep this in mind.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`sex == "m" or "M"` is not `sex == 'm' or sex == 'M'` it is `(sex == 'm') or 'M'`. So it's always `True` since `"M"` is not empty string.

For your case I'll advice use `if sex in ('m', 'M')`, `sex in ("f", "F")` etc.

Comment: OH, wow okay that was an incredibly idiotic thing for me to look over. I'mma mark this as best answer, and take the walk of shame as I realize my stupidity.

Thank you! lol

Answer (score 1):

```
if sex == 'm' or sex == 'M':
```

`... or 'M'` is always true